# How not pass some param in function

Tags: kotlin

I need to use to OPTIONAL params (from and to)
here code:

```
fun getOperationsList(
        vararg typesList: OperationType,
        operationStatusList: Array<OperationStatus>,
        from: Date, to: Date,
        callback: Callback<List<Operation>>
    ) {...}
```

here use:

```
 fun getDraftList(callback: Callback<List<Operation>>) {
        getOperationsList(
            operationStatusList = arrayOf(OperationStatus.CREATED),
            from = Date(),
            to = Date(),
            callback = callback
        )
    }
```

Nice  this work fine.

But now I want to omit from and to params
I try this:

```
 fun getDraftList2(callback: Callback<List<Operation>>) {
        getOperationsList(operationStatusList = arrayOf(OperationStatus.CREATED), callback = callback)
    }
}
```

but I get  compile error:

```
No value passed for parameter 'from' No value passed for parameter 'to'
```

How I can NOT pass `from` and `to` params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about setting default value for these params like:

```
fun getOperationsList(
        vararg typesList: OperationType,
        operationStatusList: Array<OperationStatus>,
        from: Date = Date(), 
        to: Date = Date(),
        callback: Callback<List<Operation>>
    ) {...}


getOperationsList(
        typesList = list
        operationStatusList = arrayOf(OperationStatus.CREATED),
        callback = callback
)
```

Comment: Not. Because when not pass dates then dates is infinity (whole period of times)

Comment: not sure what you want to do with these params, but you can set default as null aswell, or whatever you want, then you can ommit them :) `to: Date? = null` etc

Answer (score 2):

Use default params.
In your case you actually do not pass any parameter there, so it's completely normal that compiler fails.

Example:

```
fun test(
    p1: T1,
    p2: T2
) {
    // code here
}
```

This function can be called like this:

```
test(t1, t2)
test(p1 = t1, p2 = t2)
```

But, you cannot call this function only with one parameter, like `test(t1)`.
For cases like this you can usedefault paramters:

```
fun test(
    p1: T1,
    p2: T2? = null
) {
    // code here
}
```

And this function can be called only with one param, like `test(t1)`. In this case default param was completely omitted. Function could be called in "java-style" overloading way.

But, what with function below?

```
fun test(
    p1: T1,
    p2: T2? = null,
    p3: T3
) {
}
```

This is kind of tricky, because you always have to call this function either with named params or pass all 3 params.